# Content Porting Custom Application Data

Tags: content-porter, application-data

I'm wondering if in SDL Web 8 it's now possible to Content Port custom Application Data (App Data) related to an item?

Anyone built such a solution and can confirm it's possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this was possible since 2013? You can port custom appdata as long as you follow a convention.

Experience Manager, Translation Manager, DXA and others use this mechanism. I *thought* this was documented, but can't find the reference to it right now.

If you look under [Tridion]\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData you'll find a bunch of xml files with app data definitions. Content Porter will move the data that matches the configurations specified in there, and will convert TCM URIs (you may have to use `xlink:href` attributes to identify these URIs as "managed" links).